# Rails find_each method returning nill on console?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
User.find_each do |user|
  user.name
end
```

Output:

```
User Load (0.9ms)  SELECT  `users`.* FROM `users`  ORDER BY `users`.`id` ASC LIMIT 10000
=> nil
```

I am having records in my user table but it always return nill

Answer (score 1):

This is because you're not doing anything with the block! And in the console it's printing out the returned value of `find_each` and not what's happening within the block like you're expecting.

You can observe this by assigning your block to a variable and printing that:

```
result = User.find_each do |user|
  user.name
end
puts result  # => nil
```

Instead what you want to do is take an action within your block. So for example you could print the names of your users:

```
User.find_each do |user|
  puts user.name
end
```

Or in your case, it sounds like you're trying to gather up all the user names, so you could do something like:

```
results = User.all.map do |user|
  user.name
end
```

And this will return all the user names into `results`. This isn't very efficient and not a good long term solution if you have lots of Users, but since you're new to rails exploring how it works is more important than getting things 100% right ;)

Comment: You can also do `User.find_each.map { |user| user.name }` and get the batches and the mapping

Comment: Thanks for your answer i really appreciates, its quite helpfull

Comment: The shortest version: `User.find_each.map(&:name)`

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are not printing anything on console. 
It is not a query which will show you any result in the form of active records. Do this

```
User.find_each do |user|
 puts user.name
end
```